# Send an email alert every day at 4 am until required information or date filled

Tags: trigger, process-builder, time-dependent-workflow, workflowrule

Send an email alert every day at 4 am until required information or date filled.
Could any one please help me with this? 
Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Schedulable Interface with Messaging.SingleEmailMessage class to send an email alert at a particular interval.
Before sending an email you can check your condition if it fulfills then doesn't send email else you can send email to a particular set of user.

Below is the link for implementing schedulable Interface and messaging class in salesforce.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a time based workflow
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005245&type=1